# Using MAX in SQL Server 2005 returning all the rows instead of the last one

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table called `tblMsg` used for storing messages. I want to get the last message posted by a sender (a column in the table `Message`).

Here's my query

```
Select 
   Max(MsgId), Sender, Receiver, Contents, 
   convert(nvarchar(20), SendTime, 120) as SendTime
from 
   dbo.tblMessage 
where 
   Sender = @userName 
group by 
   Sender, Receiver, Contents, SendTime
```

Here the problem is instead of getting the last message I am getting the all the message posted by sender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are grouping by all the columns, when really you only want to group by the SenderID column. Here is a way to do this, getting the last message or *every* user, using a CTE and window functions:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT MsgId, Sender, Receiver, Contents, 
     SendTime = CONVERT(CHAR(20), SendTime, 120),
     rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Sender ORDER BY SendTime DESC)
  FROM dbo.tblMessage
)
SELECT MsgId, Sender, Receiver, Contents, SendTime
  FROM x
  WHERE rn = 1;
```

Of course if you're only after one sender at a time, you can do this without grouping at all:

```
SELECT TOP (1) MsgId, Sender, Receiver, Contents,
  SendTime = CONVERT(CHAR(20), SendTime, 120)
FROM dbo.tblMessage
WHERE Sender = @userName
ORDER BY SendTime DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 MsgId,Sender,Receiver,Contents,convert(nvarchar(20),SendTime,120) as SendTime
FROM dbo.tblMessage
WHERE Sender=@userName
ORDER BY MsgId DESC
```